# IF EXISTS shows incorrect syntax near 'IF'. expecting '.' ID, or QUOTED_ID error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2017

I have the following sql query on my local database and it runs with no errors:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MadeupTableName
```

The version of my local database is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
```

If I try to run same SQL on another SQL Server database I get this error in Intellisense:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'IF'. expecting '.', ID, or QUOTED_ID error
```

The version information on that database is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64)   Jun 17 2016 19:14:09   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Did something change between 2014 and 2017 or is there some setting that I should check?

Comment: You couldn't use that syntax in 2014. The DROP IF EXISTS was introduced with 2016.

Comment: Didn't if exists work in different context?

Comment: Not for DDL. There was the EXISTS function which checks for the existence of rows. But not drop if exists.

Comment: Looks like IF OBJECT_ID('MadeupTableName', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE MadeupTableName is the syntax I should use

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing Sean Lange's response.  DROP IF EXISTS was introduced in 2016.  For earlier SQL versions this syntax will work:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('MadeupTableName', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE MadeupTableName
```

Comment: Sorry didn't realize you were looking for the syntax. But kudos for finding the solution.